# How to get file is uploaded or not in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, bootstrap-4

I am uploading file using Bootstrap, if it is uploaded I want to show the close button (X), otherwise i don't want to show the button:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var file=$('#flFile');
      var dvClose=$('#dvClose');
      dvClose.hide();
       file.click(function(){
            dvClose.show();
       });
       $('#close').click(function(){
          file.val('');
          dvClose.hide();
      });[enter image description here][1]
    });
  </script>

<div class="input-group">
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" id="flFile"> 
    <div id='dvClose'><label style='padding-top: 7px;' class="" for="">
<span id='close' class='fa fa-close'></span></label></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect X button to be visible only when file will be uploaded.

[that X button I want to display only when file upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCTPm.jpg)

Comment: what is doing the upload? I see no code for uploading the file.

Comment: my requirement is i just want to display the close button when file is there....

Answer (score 0):

Send it by AJAX request using [FromData](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData) and listen for success event.

```
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', input.files[0]);

fetch('https://example.com', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
}).then(() => {
    console.log('File successfully uploaded.');
}).catch(() => {
    console.log('An error occurred while uploading.');
});
```

NOTE: You might have to listen some event like `onChange` for the file input and send data when this event occurs.